# How to make steps based on a condition in Coded ui test

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

I'm creating a Coded UI Test where i click a button to delete all items in a list based on the count of the item in the list , i was wondering if that is possible in Visual Studio Coded Ui Test?

Comment: Don't get you. If you want to see what happens when you have n items in the list, then you set up a list with n items in it. If something else happens with more or less in the list, then you set that up as well. Don't make your tests dependant on each other.

Comment: its a SharePoint list , i wanna delete the items in the list in order to conduct the test, if i try to delete the items in the list with no items it fail , i wanna make sure first that there is a items in the list other wise i dont have to delete

Comment: You can create an UI assertion on the first list item. If it throws an exception, you don't have to delete any item. Alternatively it is even easier to write a catch block around the UI action that deletes an item in the list. Just catch the exception without rethrowing it and log it like 'Could not delete listitem, reason: No items found'.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos Why just check if an item exists before trying to delete? Using exceptions for program flow is a bad habit to get into imo.

Comment: @stoj you are right about the bad habit, but in coded UI testing it is common practice because you're testing positive and negative scenario's with the same codeblock. The negative path is throwing the exception that you can evaluate against the testdata. It is cleaner than just a boolean flag, because you can actually read (Exception.Message) what went wrong and output it to the TestContext or you can make decisions based on the type of exception: AssertFailureExceptions for test related checks, any other for serious unexpected problems that you rethrow.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos In this case you don't gain anything from using an Exception if the item doesn't exist it doesn't exist. If you wrap the delete function in a Try/Catch how do you handle a failure in a confirmation dialog swallow it because it matches a similar exception? Or do you wrap individual actions in Try/Catch blocks? Seems like a lot of extra trouble when you could just check for the number of list items or for the existence of the first item.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the list is a supported control (and it should be) it will expose the number of items that are in the list and you can use that to decide if you want to delete items. If the list is only partially supported but items in the list are visible to CodedUI you can check for existence of the first item and decided to delete items from there.